# Is this alternative odd function equation valid?

Tags: functions, symmetry, symmetric-functions

An odd function is a function where:

$$f(-x) = -f(x)$$

Is this alternative form valid ?

$$f(x) = -f(-x)$$

I'm asking because an odd function graphically is symmetrical with respects to the origin. 
Which means that the x and y point's signs are flipped.

The second form seems easier to read (assuming it's valid).

Comment: Both are valid, but actually the first is easier to read.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I guess I like seeing f(x) without any sign changes. Similar to the even function equation. The first form has negatives on both sides.

Comment: $a = -b \iff b = -a\,$ so, yes, both say the same thing.

Comment: It's valid.  Just multiply both sides by -1.  There's no accounting for taste.  I prefer the conventional.  It seems more direct somehow.

Comment: @fleablood I think the second form does a good job at showing what is occurring graphically (change of signs). But yes, it's simply taste and I'll stick with the conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(CW; just ensuring this question registers as answered.)

**Yes**: As remarked in the comments, the two equations are equivalent. This can be seen by simply multiplying both sides of one equation by $-1$ to obtain the other equation.

As to which one "seems easier to read," this is -- of course -- a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as $(-1)^2=1$. You have:

$$f(-x) = -f(x) \Rightarrow (-1)f(-x) = (-1)(-f(x)) \Rightarrow -f(-x) = (-1)(-1)f(x) = f(x) \Rightarrow f(x) = -f(-x)$$

and of course the reverse:

$$f(x) = -f(-x) \Rightarrow (-1)f(x) = (-1)(-1)f(-x) \Rightarrow -f(x) = f(-x) \Rightarrow f(-x) = -f(x)$$

---

While what seems easier to read is a matter of taste they generalize differently. If you replace negation with another operation(*) they will no longer be the same - not that it matters in your context, in another context one of the definitions might be more natural than the other.

(*) For example homogenity is a stronger condition which is defined as $cf(x) = f(cx)$ for any constant $c$ (not only $-1$). Here you see it might be more "natural" to define oddness with the first definition.